# Formato JSON desde PHP se envía incorrecto a través de Ajax

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery, ajax

estoy desarrollando un sistema pequeño, cuanta con un pequeño formulario donde se envían 4 parámetros vía Ajax hacia PHP y se realiza una consulta, hasta ahí todo en orden, sin embargo, al devolver la consulta en formato JSON solo se envía 1 valor.

El código siguiente es el que muestra el valor retornado desde la consulta de la BD en la consola:

```
success: function(valor){
        valor = jQuery.parseJSON(valor);
        console.log(valor);
        $('#bombas_recomendadas_card').css("display", "block");
```

Se muestran los datos de **la única columna de la tabla que envía**.

El siguiente código es en donde agrego los valores a un array después de hacer la consulta(*la consulta funciona, hice múltiples pruebas y está todo en orden, de hecho, por cada bomba con X GPM, hay un filtro con el mismo valor, por lo que **mínimo se deben desplegar 2 valores en caso de que encuentre una bomba/filtro con ese GPM***).

```
while($bombas = mysqli_fetch_array($respuesta)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($respuesta)> 0){
        $bomba = array(
            'nombre' => $bombas['nombre'],
            'hp' => $bombas['hp'],
            'gpm' => $bombas['gpm'],
            'tipo' => $bombas['tipo'],
            'gpm_enviado' => round($gpm, 2)
        );
    }
    return json_encode($bomba); 
}
```

Una vez se realiza esto, el mensaje que se imprime en la consola es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Así mismo me gustaría preguntar si es más factible realizarlo de esta manera, o enviar directo los datos de Ajax a la vista y crear un `while` para imprimir el listado de elementos.*

De antemano gracias por el apoyo.

**Nota 1: Si el código de `return json_encode($bomba);` lo pongo dentro del bucle `while` se muestra el PRIMER valor que trae de la BD, pero si lo pongo fuera, trae el ÚLTIMO.**

**Nota 2: Hay un archivo de por medio entre el JS y el archivo donde se hace la consulta, lo único que hace es recibir los datos del Ajax y pasarlos al archivo donde se hace la consulta.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli` devuelve un recurso con las diferentes filas que haya en la consulta, por tanto, se usa `while` para ir leyendo ese recurso fila por fila. Entonces, no tiene sentido hacer un `return` dentro del `while`.

O una cosa o la otra:

- si necesitas varias filas, agota el `while`, llenando dentro la respuesta y fuera del `while` haz el `return`
- si necesitas una sola fila, el `while` no es necesario, simplemente aplica el `fetch` que obtendrá esa única fila que necesitas, y, para evitar traer fila que no usarás nunca, agrega `LIMIT 1` al final de tu consulta.

Aparte de eso, debes verificar si hay filas antes de pasar a leer los datos, no durante. Lo digo porque verificas con `mysqli_num_rows` dentro del `while`, cuando debe ser al revés: primero verificas si hay filas, luego pasas a leer esas filas, usando el `while`, como dije más arriba.

Finalmente, `mysqli` tiene el método [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) que te asocia directamente los valores a sus nombres de columna, de modo que no tengas que hacerlo manualmente, además, el método que estás usando en tu código te trae los valores **dos veces**, como array asociativo y como array numérico.

Asumiré que necesitas `while`:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($respuesta)> 0){
    $mData=array('status'=>true);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($respuesta)){
        /*
           Debido a que hemos usado mysqli_fetch_assoc
           ya no hace falta meter cada columna => valor manualmente
           porque eso lo hace ya fetch_assoc
           El valor calculado sí lo metemos a mano
           porque no viene en la consulta
           Asumo que $gmp es una variable definida previamente
           pues no la veo en este contexto ¿?
        */
        $row['gpm_enviado']=round($gpm, 2);
        $mData['data'][]=$row;
    }
} else {
    $mData=array('status'=>false , 'msg'=>'No se encontraron filas');
}
return json_encode($mData);
```

Si observas, cuando hay filas, yo he puesto en `$mData` una clave llamada `status` con un valor establecido a `true`, y los diferentes datos dentro de una clave `data`. En caso de error, la clave `status` será `false` y habrá un mensaje en la clave `msg` con el error ocurrido. Esto es para dar **coherencia** en el cliente. Así, verificando la  clave `status` sabrás si hubo error, pudiendo mostrar en ese caso un mensaje al usuario.

Esa **coherencia** se aplicaría de este modo al recibir la respuesta:

```
success: function(valor){       
        valor = jQuery.parseJSON(valor);
        if(valor.status) {
            /*
               Hay datos, leerlos ...
               NÓTESE que las diferentes filas estarán en 
               la propiedad data de valor
            */
            console.log(valor.data);
        } else {
            /*No hay datos, mostrar mensaje de error u otra cosa*/
            console.log(valor.msg);
        }
        $('#bombas_recomendadas_card').css("display", "block");
```

Comment: Funciona a la perfección con las correcciones indicadas. Muchas gracias por el apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

Define la variable $bomba afuera del bucle while, ejemplo

```
$bomba = array();     
while($bombas = mysqli_fetch_array($respuesta)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($respuesta)> 0){
       array_push($bomba,'nombre' => $bombas['nombre'],
            'hp' => $bombas['hp'],
            'gpm' => $bombas['gpm'],
            'tipo' => $bombas['tipo'],
            'gpm_enviado' => round($gpm, 2));
    }
    return json_encode($bomba); 
}
```

Prueba con eso, debes crear la variable que contreda el arreglo (ARRAY) fuera del bucle, luego en cada iteración haces un push de esos datos y listo, debe funcionar.